# Measure on Borel sets

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

If $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are two Borel measures with $\mu_1([a,b])\le \mu_2([a,b])$ for all $a<b$, how we can prove that $\mu_1(A)\le \mu_2(A)$ for all Borel sets $A$? (All sets are from $\mathbb{R}$)
Unfortunately, the set of intervals $[a,b]$ is not even a semi-ring, so I don't even know how to start here. Would be nice if someone has some ideas about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Borel measure is on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, everything is in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Have you tried showing it for the half open intervals and then using the Dynkin Lemma?

Comment: Thanks for advice, but how can Dynkin Lemma help?

Comment: Show that the inequality holds for the open interval $(\alpha,\beta)$. Then why it holds for an arbitrary open $G$ with $\mu_2(G)<\infty$? After that take a Borel set $A$ with $\mu_2(A)<\infty$ and approximate that with an open set $G$. After that what can we say for $\mu_2(A)=\infty$?

Comment: I don't see how i can show it for open intervals. I can only show it for disjunct unions of closed intervalls. But how can (a,b) be represented as a disjunct union of closed intervalls?

Comment: You dont necessarily have to represent it as disjoint unions. You can also work with increasing closed intervals.

Comment: How exactly can I approximate a borel set with an open set? Is there a monoton sequence of open sets with their union equal to a borel set?

Comment: Use $\mu_2(E)=\inf\{\mu_2(G):\, E\subseteq G, G \ open\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This answer is much longer than a solution to this problem needs to be because I'm explaining everything in detail -- you can easily write this down in 2-3 lines.

I don't know if you're familiar with the Monotone Class Lemma, but this seems like a standard application. Anything that relates the properties of measures that hold under limits (in this case, weak inequality) is usually solvable using this lemma. So, for future reference, if you're up against a problem that asks gives you a property of measures that holds for a certain class of "nice" sets (in this case, intervals), and th eproperty holds under limits (in this case, the inequality), then MCL is probably a useful tool.

*Step 1.* Notice that this holds for half open half closed intervals of the form $(a,b]$. Now that $(a,b] = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [a+\frac{1}{n}, b]$ so,
$$
\mu_{1}((a,b]) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{1}([a + \frac{1}{n}, b]) \leq lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{2}([a+\frac{1}{n}, b]) = \mu_{2}((a,b])
$$

*Step 2.* Recall the Monotone Class Lemma (or look it up, if you aren't familiar with it): If $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$, denoted $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, is equal to the smallest monotone class containing $\mathcal{A}$, denoted $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$. A monotone class is a collection of sets which is closed under increasing unions and decreasing intersections.

*Step 3.* We will now apply this result. Our algebra $\mathcal{A}$ will be the algebra generated by half open half closed intervals $(a,b]$ (which, you may recall, consists of disjoint unions of half-open half-closed intervals). If we can show that the set
$$
B = \{A \in \mathcal{B}: \mu_{1}(A) \leq \mu_{2}(B)\}
$$
is a monotone class which contains $\mathcal{A}$, then it must contain $\mathcal{M}(A)$, so by the Monotone Class Lemma is must contain $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, i.e. all Borel sets. But this is fairly straightforward, since if $\{A_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a collection in $B$ such that $A_{n} \uparrow A$, then $\mu_{1}(A) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{1}(A_{n}) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{2}(A_{n}) = \mu_{2}(A)$ (and same for decreasing sequences), which shows that $A \in B$. This shows that $B$ is a monotone class and we're done.

Comment: I was just talking about this with someone so might as well complete my answer here as well: It does NOT suffice to use open sets $(a,b)$ in the MCL because these do not form any nice algebra for you to work with. For MCL problems you always want to work with the algebra generated by left-open right-closed intervals since these give you a nice algebra